# Rendering multiple model configurations

Tags: rendering

I have a model of a furniture
I have these parameters :

- 3 types of wood,
- 5 colors of the frame
- 6 size.

It's 90 possible configurations of the furniture.

How can I manage the scenes and render the batch of the different configurations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameters that varies can be keyframed, you can do something like that :

- add keys for your frame color on frames 1 to 5
- add keys for your wood on frames 5, 10, 15 (5*n 3 times)
- add keys for your size on frames 15, 30, 45, 60 ,90 (15*n 6 times)

In the Graph editor, make all your channels **cyclic extrapolation**, and all your keys **constant interpolation**.

Select a picture format as render output (not a video format), and render a 90 frames animation : you will get 90 different pictures.

Comment: I suspect the different sizes require different base models, not just a simple scaling. The technique still applies though, and probably eases the process even with multiple models. Anyway +1 from me

Comment: For the different base models, you can animate the "visibility" property (the eye/camera in the outliner).